# django foreign key of foreign key

Tags: mysql, django

I have the following classes for a rolodex example:
I have an issue that involves accessing a foreign key of a foreign key. Code snippets below:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
    ...

class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    ...

class City(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey('State')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

class People(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

Now, I need to get the count of people in each state (country). I can write an SQL query like this:

```
select s.name, count(*) as total
    from person p join city c join state s
    where p.city_id = c.id and c.state_id = s.id
    group by s.name
    order by total desc;`
```

This gives me each state name and the number of people from that state. How do I do this query in django?

Comment: If you have the state, try something like: People.objects.filter(city__state__pk=my_state_pk).count()...i am a little rusty at this but it must be something close to that.

Comment: I would need to loop through all the "pk"s of the state; I want the top 100 states, top being defined by the number of people from that state.

Comment: Hmmm...maybe State.objects.annotate(num_people=Count(states='city__people_set').order_by('-states')[:100]

Comment: I am not sure if the city__people_set part will work tho. Check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: cdvv7788: State.objects.annotate(num_people=Count(states='city__people_set').order_by('-sta‌​tes') doesn't work.

Comment: Whats the error? something like city does not have a field named people_set?